# php writes files that I can't access - windows IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, windows-10

I have a php page that writes files onto my local PC, into a specific folder named UploadedImages. This all works fine. The problem is that when I go to look at the file (always an image file -- a .png in this case), and double-click it, windows says I don't have permission to view it. Again, file permissions on the UploadedImages folder is **wide open** (Everyone -> Read/Write), and my login account has **Full Control**, and my login account is the Owner of the folder.

If I right-click the file and go into permissions, it shows that I have no permissions on the file. I can go in and grant myself ownership and permissions, then view it -- but it makes no sense that I have to do this every time.

How can I permanently solve this so that every file my php script writes into that folder I have automatic/full access to it?

I am running Windows 10, IIS 10.0 and PHP 5.6.11. It appears that IUSR account is getting the permissions, but why would I (the ADMIN on the folder) have all my rights revoked just because php writes a file there? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is try to run web server under certain user (not admin) to which you have full access rights.
Second possible solution: maybe your virtual host config contains directive which force server to work under admin or user to which you dont have access - try to change it.

Comment: I can't find where in IIS to do this. Detailed steps?

Answer (score 0):

@SweatCoder: You said:

> Again, file permissions on the UploadedImages folder is wide open (Everyone -> Read/Write), and my login account has Full Control, and my login account is the Owner of the folder.
>   [...]
>   If I right-click the file and go into permissions, it shows that I have no permissions on the file. I can go in and grant myself ownership and permissions, then view it

This is what's called "inheritance". You need to set inheritance on the folder, so permissions on files are inherited from the parent directory.

//edit: see the `icacls` help information in cmd.exe:
`icacls /?`

Comment: Can this only be done via command line (icacls)? Not through UI? I kind of thought about inheritance when I was in there (UI), but couldn't find how to make it do it.

Comment: I went in and looked, and inheritance was already enabled. Each time a new file gets written, permissions are broken again regardless. The odd thing is I have other local php apps on my pc that write files and none of them have this problem.